# List combination (n choose k) that returns tuple (chosen, not chosen) instead of just (chosen)

Tags: f#

I want to alter the following function (or create an entirely new one) so that it returns (chosen, not chosen) instead of just (chosen):

```
let rec comb n l = 
    match n, l with
    | 0, _ -> [[]]
    | _, [] -> []
    | k, (x::xs) -> List.map ((@) [x]) (comb (k-1) xs) @ comb k xs
```

Currently,

```
comb 2 ["R";"G";"B"]
```

returns

```
[["R"; "G"]; ["R"; "B"]; ["G"; "B"]]
```

I want it to return

```
[(["R"; "G"], ["B"]); (["R"; "B"], ["G"]); (["G"; "B"], ["R"])]
```

Most of my problem is that I have a lack of understanding about what is going on in the last line of the current function.

Comment: [`List.partition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353782.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should look something like this:

```
let rec comb n l = 
    match n, l with
    | 0, l -> [[],l]
    | _, [] -> []
    | k, (x::xs) -> 
        [for (yes,no) in comb (k-1) xs do
            yield x::yes,no
         for (yes,no) in comb k xs do
            yield yes,x::no]
```